# How to inform user about running tasks?

Tags: java, servlets, web-applications, progress-bar

i have some web app,which perform some time consuming task.And the problem is that i can't show to user that process is really running.
I search through web for some progress bar or something like that,but all that i fond was about file uploading.Is it possible to send some output messages or create progress bar with some dynamically changed labels about situation to user while main process is running?I'm novice in web and i would be glad if you show me some direction.

Comment: You can have look at this `http://api.jqueryui.com/progressbar/`

Answer (score 0):

You really did not offer much information on what you are trying to do. If if you want what i think you want, you should just display some text on the screen at certain points in your time consuming code portion.